# Continuously add new variables until a condition is satisfied python

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of code that will repeatedly add new variables until the user says "no".

Current code:

```
fizzydrinks = [] 
max = 0
while max == 0:
    ask = input("Do you want to add an item to the list?")
    if ask == "Y":
        item = input("Enter your fizzy drink to the List: ")
    elif ask =="N":
        max = max + 1
    fizzydrinks.append(item)
    print (fizzydrinks)
```

The problem with this code is that when you enter the final variable and say "no" to adding more items, it repeats the last item you entered in the list.

This is the output:

```
Enter your fizzy drink to the List: Coke
['Coke']
Do you want to add an item to the list?Y
Enter your fizzy drink to the List: Tango
['Coke', 'Tango']
Do you want to add an item to the list?N
['Coke', 'Tango', 'Tango']
```

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: Please, add your code and point out specific problems, this is not a tutorials site...

Comment: Your own goal is giving you a clue: " ... items in the `list`."

Comment: You accumulate objects by adding them to a list or other container, not by creating new variables on the fly.

Comment: Updated for problem speification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your program to quit the `while` loop as soon as the user enters `N`.

```
fizzydrinks = [] 

while True:
    ask = input("Do you want to add an item to the list?")
    if ask == "Y":
        item = input("Enter your fizzy drink to the List: ")
    else:
        break
    fizzydrinks.append(item)
    print (fizzydrinks)
```

This uses the typical `while True:` loop and a `break` as soon as the exit condition is met.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing i had to change was the print fizzydrinks and the end shouldn't be indented but thank you so much for the help. Much appreciated